# mapbox accessToken in .env file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, environment-variables, mapbox

I set up a new create-my-app and added this basic example as the App component:

```
import {Component} from 'react';
import ReactMapGL from 'react-map-gl';

class App extends Component {

  state = {
    viewport: {
      width: 400,
      height: 400,
      latitude: 37.7577,
      longitude: -122.4376,
      zoom: 8
    }
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <ReactMapGL
        {...this.state.viewport}
        onViewportChange={(viewport) => this.setState({viewport})}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

On running, it gives an error because I havent given the token yet. I read that I can pass it to App as a prop. So in the index file, I tried this:

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <App mapboxApiAccessToken={"sjdd"} />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

but it still gives the same error. How can I use an .env file to add the accessToken and what exactly should I write in it?

Comment: In a react app no strings are secret or private. Make sure you don't add any secrets here

Comment: If it's not a secret use https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv

Answer (score 1):

To expose Mapbox token as environment variable for Create React App:

- create a file called `.env` in the root of your project
- define  environment variable to store Mapbox token, e.g. `REACT_APP_MAPBOX_TOKEN`  **Note**: you must create a custom environment variables beginning with `REACT_APP_`  ([details](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables/))

Once created, it will be exposed in your JS as `process.env.REACT_APP_MAPBOX_TOKEN`, for example:

```
<ReactMapGL
    mapboxApiAccessToken={process.env.REACT_APP_MAPBOX_TOKEN}
    {...this.state.viewport}
    onViewportChange={(viewport) => this.setState({ viewport })}
  />
```